# Redirect an Amazon-purchased domain to an existing URL

Tags: redirect, amazon-route53

I am hoping this is simple for the experts on here! I purchased a domain for my wedding on AWS Route 53 because the zola service is not an easy to remember URL.  I know that it is possible to instantiate an s3 instance in which all it does is redirect to the zola URL, but that would cost money as I have exceeded my free tier year.

Is there a way to just have route 53 automatically redirect to the zola URL?  Perhaps someone here could point me to a tutorial on the web or somewhere that explains this, or confirms that this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here is AWS documentation on it: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/.

In summary, you create an S3 bucket for your Route 53 url, set it up for static site hosting and configure it to redirect to another domain. Then point a Route 53 alias entry to the bucket.